# tikz-qtree inside gb4e example not centered when bidi is loaded

Tags: polyglossia, linguistics, tikz-qtree, bidi, gb4e

I am using `tikz-qtree` to draw syntax trees that go inside of `gb4e` examples.
I was very happy that I was able to get them to center by following this answer: [Centering trees](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/259031/centering-trees)

However, I then decided that I wanted to use some Arabic text in my paper, so I loaded Arabic as the other language via `polyglossia`. Suddenly, none of my trees were centered. I'm guessing that the problem has something to do with loading `bidi`, which `polyglossia` does when you add a right-to-left language, but I'm not sure how to get around it.

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{english}
% Uncomment the following line to see the problem behavior:
%\setotherlanguage{arabic}
\usepackage{gb4e}

\begin{document}
Here is an example tree that I want to be centered.
\begin{exe}
    \ex
    \hfil
    \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline]
        \Tree [.DP
                [.D the ]
                [.NP [.N center ] ] ]
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \hfil
\end{exe}
\end{document}
```

Here is a photo of the desired output:
[image: A centered tree in gb4e]

And here is the output I get when bidi is loaded:
[image]

Comment: Welcome! I get the same result whether I uncomment the line or not with XeTeX. With LuaTeX, it doesn't work at all and centring seems the least of the issues.

Comment: I can't reproduce this either.

Comment: Weird... I had been using XeLaTeX, through TeXShop on a Mac, which has the problem I described. I had never tried LuaLaTeX, but I just tried it and it works with including Arabic or without it.

Comment: @AidanKaplan As far as I know, the `bidi` package (which is loaded by `polyglossia` if you select an RTL language like Arabic or Hebrew) is for use with XeLaTeX only, not LuaLaTeX, and so if your document requires Arabic, you should not use LuaLaTeX. And your sample document works fine with XeLaTeX for me.

Comment: Hi Aidan! I also can't replicate the effect you're describing with XeLaTeX.

Comment: Have you tested to see whether the effect is still there for some other kind of box instead of the `tikzpicture`?

Comment: Also, your OS/editor configuration reminds me of [this issue](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/46199/42880). If you add `% !TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode` to the top of the file, does that change the behavior?

Comment: Hi Jason! Unfortunately adding that line doesn't change anything about the output. And that's good to know that LuaLaTeX doesn't work with `polyglossia`

Comment: LuaLaTeX does work with `polyglossia`, but not `bidi` so not for RTL scripts. Can you put `\listfiles` before `\documentclass` and post the list of files you get on the console/in the log? I can only think you have an old version of something or a stale confg file.

Comment: Also, just to be sure, make a new directory and copy the code from the question to an empty document. Save into the new directory and compile there. This is a sanity check, basically, to rule out imponderables.

Comment: I just met with Aidan (my student), and we think the problem may be due to an out-of-date distribution. However, he wants to hold off on updating because he is finishing a thesis and doesn't want to break everything...

Comment: We did determine that the same effect happens inside any list item, whether from `gb4e`'s `exe` environment or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The original poster is my student, so I met with him in person to debug this problem since none of the commenters were able to replicate the issue he reported.

It turns out that the problem is not specific to `tikz-qtree` or `gb4e`. It is caused by a bug in older versions of `bidi` (previously reported [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/275170/42880)) that interferes with the `tikzpicture` environment of `tikz`. With these older versions of `bidi`, you can see the effect in any list environment, not just `gb4e`'s `exe` environment.

There are two solutions:

1. Update `bidi` to the current version, which no longer has the bug. In general this is what I would recommend, but Aidan has opted not to do this for now because he is nearly finished writing a thesis and doesn't want other things in his setup to break.
2. Surround the `tikzpicture` environment in a `\makebox{}`, as suggested in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/275170/42880).